# Obtener archivo .txt con URL relativa con JS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fetch, promesas, txt

Estoy tratando de obtener un archivo .txt cargado en wordpress en multimedio con la la " url wp-content/uploads/2022/03/ " . Había visto que se puede hacer con fetch y devuelve una promesa pero lo hago y se queda en pendiente la respuesta, y aunque si puedo ver los datos del archivo, no puedo hacer uso de ellos, porque se queda en pendiente.

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
function getData(){
return fetch('wp-content/uploads/2022/03/hc-gartner-texts.txt')
 .then(res => res.text())
 .then(content => {
   var text = content.split(/\n/);  
   return text;
 });  
}  
console.log(getData())
```

y me devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que el "Hola" en la respuesta es el texto que deseo recibir.

No sé si haya una forma más sencilla, o en su defecto si pueda acceder a ese texto.

Gracias.

Comment: Solo puedes acceder al texto desde dentro del `then`.

Comment: Y si lo quiero colocar en una etiqueta html?, cómo lo puedo almacenar en una variable?

Comment: La promesa nunca está terminando. Puedes mostrar el código donde usas esa promesa?

Comment: @vmporcayom colócalo dentro de la etiqueta html dentro del mismo `then`. Ahí mismo haces todo lo que necesitas, llamas a la función que se encargará de procesar esos datos, o lo que sea que requieras.